# How to share model between modules

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to develop a Backbone Marionette application. I need to be able to edit a model but I have no idea how to get the model into the edit form.

I am using modules for each "responsibility" in the app. For example one module for listing users and another one for handling editing users.

What is the best way of sharing the model between the List module and the Edit module?
I need to support both opening the edit form programatically and with a route.

Thankful for all help regarding CRUD for Marionette in general too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you reconsider separating the "list" and "edit" tasks into separate modules.  Think of a module as a family of related features that constitute a single deliverable. Would you ever edit a user without out listing users?  Not likely.

Separation of Concerns is important, but that separation can still occur within your module. For example, you've already identified at least four different things, each with their own responsibilities, but related to the 'user':

```
UserListView -> CollectionView
UserItemView -> ItemView
UserEditView -> Layout or ItemView
UserController -> Controller
UserRouter -> AppRouter
```

Start simple: create a module with UserListView and UserItemView, a Backbone.Collection, and a Backbone.Model.  When you have successfully fetched the collection, create and show in a collectionView.